# Send screen fields values to FB60 selection screen

Tags: abap, sap-erp, dynpro

I have created a screen with all fields under BASIC DATA tab of transaction 'FB60'. Using module pool program I have created 2 buttons

- TRANSFER
- EXIT

Now my question is: when I click TRANSFER the data entered in my screen should transfer to the corresponding fields of BASIC DATA tab of transaction `FB60`. Is it possible to do like that? If yes please suggest me the ways....

Answer (score 0):

You should call a BAPI to create the incoming invoice, you can try using the FM `BAPI_INCOMINGINVOICE_CREATE1`

Comment: It depends on what 'transfer' means in the question. The values in his screen will be 'tranferred' to FB60 after calling that BAPI.

Answer (score 0):

Just submit report will help you, man, simple sumbit...

```
SUBMIT 'SAPMF05A' WITH accnt = 'value'
                  WITH bldat = 'value'
...
```